# Still having duplicate vaues in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I already took advises on the web regarding to prevent duplicate values from saving to the mysql table but it still saves it and I already placed echo statements and exit to ensure this doesn't happen but it still has. Here is the code that I used and edited to my preferences:

```
$line = array();
$file = fopen("D:/Documents/Documents/LOGS.txt", "r");
while (! feof($file))
{
    $line[] = fgetcsv($file, 4096);

    foreach ($line as $value)
    {
        $newline = explode(" ", $value[1]);
        $date = trim($newline[0]);
        $time = trim($newline[1]);

        $check = mysqli_query($cxn, "select * from temprec where EmpID = '$value[0]'
            and ValidDate = '$date' and ValidTime = '$time'") or die("Couldn't execute
            query");
        $checkrows = mysqli_num_rows($check);
        if ($checkrows > 0) {
            echo "data already saved";
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($cxn, "insert ignore into      
                temprec(EmpID,ValidDate,ValidTime) values('$value[0]','$date','$time')") or
                die("Couldn't execute query");
        }
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

Note: the logs.txt contains data from a biometrics machine and it contains too much duplicate values.

Comment: Add unique indexes to your table

Comment: sorry i will edit it.

Comment: i think juergen is onto something there, Ray

Comment: Is your php script in the same html page that calls it?

Comment: I already tried adding primary key and unique id but it just increments and still save the duplicate with different id even though i set the values to be checked for duplicates.

Comment: its just a script to save the text file to mysql table.

Comment: I am now trying the syntax of replace into hopefully it will work.

Comment: still no luck I also used on duplicate key update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the check query. In string
`"select * from temprec where EmpID = '$value[0]' and ValidDate = '$date' and ValidTime = '$time'"` variable $value[0] parces as just $value and you get query like this `"select * from temprec where EmpID = 'array[0]' and ValidDate = '$date' and ValidTime = '$time'"`.

Using '{}' should fix it: `"select * from temprec where EmpID = '${value[0]}' and ValidDate = '$date' and ValidTime = '$time'"`.

Comment: thank you for the advice I will change it according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried echoing your `"insert ignore into temprec(EmpID,ValidDate,ValidTime) values('$value[0]','$date','$time')") or
die("Couldn't execute query"` for you to be sure if your query shows the right query?

Comment: its okay i already solve it my bad i should only have made unique the time value....

Comment: piece of advise, as much as possible, avoid executing query inside a loop. Your select statement in the loop contributes much to your query execution time. and your insert statement can be done after the loop. Just construct the data in a string you need to insert then at the end of the loop, concatenate it to your insert statement